# check if bluetooth is connected to any device with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I need to check if the device is connected to any device via Bluetooth.
This is my activity where I launch activity for Bluetooth settings. ``

```
        
            receiver = BluetoothModeReceiver()
            IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED).also {
                registerReceiver(receiver, it)
            
            val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(settingsIntent)
        }
```

And this is the broadcast receiver:

```
class BluetoothModeReceiver :BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val isDeviceConnected = intent?.getBooleanExtra("state",false) ?: return
        if(isDeviceConnected){
            Log.i("Broadcast", "Happened ")
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use intents like BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED and ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED but none of them work. When I connect the phone to any device that log in receiver doesn't get printed in the logcat. Any ideas why it doesn't work? They would be appreciated.

Comment: would you check the action filter with ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED?

Comment: @AbolfazlAbbasi i checked. still doesnt work